# GET query based on timestamp

Tags: elasticsearch

I’m looking for help on building a query that will retrieve the last number of documents for a given time frame, for example last 30 minutes.
The documents are syslogs like:

```
{
"_index": "logstash-2017.01.16",
"_type": "syslog",
"_id": "AVmnIUFGd2leAWt2KJSr",
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"@timestamp": "2017-01-16T11:54:48.318Z",
"syslog_severity_code": 5,
"syslog_facility": "user-level",
"@version": "1",
"host": "10.0.0.1",
"syslog_facility_code": 1,
"message": "Test Syslog Message",
"type": "syslog",
"syslog_severity": "notice",
tags": [
"_grokparsefailure"
]
}
```

My idea is to build this query into another script that will check for new items being added to ES.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Range Query`:

```
GET index/type/_count
{
 "query": {
    "range": {
       "@timestamp": {
          "from": "now-30m",
          "to" : "now"
       }
     }
  }
 }
```

This will give output like :

```
 {
 "count": 2,
 "_shards": {
  "total": 5,
  "successful": 5,
  "failed": 0
 }
}
```

where `count` will carry the number of document matched.

Read more about `Range Query` [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#ranges-on-dates)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this works for us when querying all documents in an indice but instead we’re wanting to query the amount of documents in an indice, so there are two methods tried:

GET /_cat/count/<INDICE_NAME>?v

This one gives us a good count but we want to be able to use this in another script so ideally we would like to retrieve only the objects "count" in the “total” field as per the below query:

GET /<INDICE_NAME>/ _stats

Ideally we would have an output of just the number.

Comment: Thanks, would there be a filter where we could match and then display only the result rather than the rest of the array?

Comment: Sorry.. But I did not get your question. Can you explain what output do you want?

Comment: I just want to see the number value, such as: count object in the total array when running GET indice/_stats

Comment: Hi, to expand on this; when running "GET indice/_stats", we only want to retrieve the total field and the count object within.